# Method of quickly factorizing higher degree polynomials without rational roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

For a problem I need to factorise $x^4+2x^3-8x^2-6x+15$. The solution is $(x^2+2x-5)(x^2-3)$. Is there some way I can quickly factorise this? This is only a small part of a long and complicated sum which I need to do in 4-5 minutes and I can't spend a lot of time using trial and error method to find the roots, especially when the roots are not rational. Is there some method by which I can factorise this without taking too much time? I cannot use rational root theorem here.

Comment: Why do you need to factorise polynomials like this?

Comment: Typing `factor(x^4+2*x^3-8*x^2-6*x+15)` in PARI/GP returns the factors instantaneously, so you can use it to factorize many polynomials within 4-5 minutes

Comment: I actually need it while writing an exam, I was doing a mock test and one of the questions in it had a solution which needed the factorization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the [theorem of Gauss on content says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)), once there are no rational roots, the remaining possibility is, with integers $a,b,c,d,$
$$  (x^2 + ax+b)(x^2 + cx + d) $$
which can be reduced to four cases,
$$  (x^2 + ax+1)(x^2 + cx + 15) \; , $$
$$  (x^2 + ax-1)(x^2 + cx - 15) \; , $$
$$  (x^2 + ax+3)(x^2 + cx + 5) \; , $$
$$  (x^2 + ax-3)(x^2 + cx - 5) \; , $$
so now investigate what $a,c$ might be in each case.

To get the correct $x^3$ 
$$  (x^2 + ax+1)(x^2 + (2-a)x + 15) \; , $$
$$  (x^2 + ax-1)(x^2 + (2-a)x - 15) \; , $$
$$  (x^2 + ax+3)(x^2 + (2-a)x + 5) \; , $$
$$  (x^2 + ax-3)(x^2 + (2-a)x - 5) \; . $$
For each, you pick $a$ so that the coefficient of $x$ also comes out correct, namely $-6.$ **In case $a$ turns out to be an integer**, finally check what the coefficient of $x^2$ comes to.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly! Actually the question I was doing was to find the product of the uncommon factors of x4+2x3−8x2−6x+15 and x3+4x2-x-10. x3+ 4x2- x - 10 with rational root theorem evaluates to (x^2+2x-5)(x+2) and x4+2x3−8x2−6x+15  as per your method evaluates to (x2+2x−5)(x2−3). I was wondering if there is some method (perhaps polynomial division) to directly get these results without factoring the individual polynomials?